# Hudson+Maven+SVN get this FATAL: Couldn't find any executable in D:\Program Files (x86)\Maven\apache-maven-3.3.9

Tags: maven, svn, hudson

I build a continuous integration system with Hudson+Maven+ SVN，When I build a job I get this error

[image]

While I use maven by command line, it succeed. the configuration of Hudson is below

[image]

the environment variable is set well

Comment: To solve it:

Go to the Maven installation folder
Go to bin
Make sure you can see file extensions
Duplicate mvn.cmd and mvnDebug.cmd and rename those copies to have the extension.bat
Try building the project now

Comment: @Cù Đức Hiếu When suggesting edits, don't just replace the image links with the images - fix _everything_ that is wrong with the post.

Answer (score 0):

Hudson can't find the maven executables. You should point the `MAVEN_HOME` environment variable to the `C:\YOUR_PATH_TO_MAVEN_DIRECTORY\bin` directory and not to the installation directory itself.